# ruby array, get all elements from second to last

Tags: ruby, arrays

My method:

```
 def scroll_images
   images_all[1..images_all.length]
 end
```

I don't like that I'm calling `images_all` twice, just wondering if there's a good trick to call `self` or something similar to make this a little cleaner.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: get second element to last

Comment: You're not "calling" images_all, you're referencing elements of it. Grabbing `images_all.length` is a constant time operation, so what's to refactor?

Comment: @pjs `images_all` could be a (expensive) method call returning an array

Comment: @Stefan `images_all` sure looks like an array to me.

Comment: @pjs `def images_all; query_remote_webserver_for_large_array(); end`

Comment: @Ajedi32 Easily dealt with by `def scroll_images; result = images_all; result[1..result.length]; end` if that's the case.

Comment: @pjs Well, that's certainly *one* solution. Feel free to post as an answer, or see below for other solutions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `-1` instead of the length:

```
 def scroll_images
   images_all[1..-1] # `-1`: the last element, `1..-1`: The second to the last.
 end
```

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a[1..-1]
# => [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: ahh there you go! thank you so much

Answer (score 14):

You can get the same result in a clearer way using the [`Array#drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-drop) method:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.drop(1)
# => [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: See also: [`Array#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-take) for the other side of the array.

Comment: be careful, it mutates the existing array

Comment: @Stiig No, it doesn't

Comment: @toro2k ohh, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more way using [`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at) :-

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a.values_at(1..-1) # => [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually modifying the values of `images_all` i.e. explicitly drop the first element permanently, just use `shift`:

```
images_all.shift
```

Comment: good to know, I just need to access second to last element in array.